# What makes you, you?

Tags: identity

Is it your name or your body or your mind?

Also, similarly, fans of a certain sports club will cheer for the sports kit and the name. The players change and so does their coach, but the name and kit stay the same.

Is it the same situation with your identity?

Comment: This is called the question of personal identity. It's an amazingly large question that ties in with mind-body, culture, consciousness, and many other large philosophical issues.

Comment: If you really ask this question and seriously attempt to answer it then you have become a mystic.You won't find an answer in our local Russellian tradition of philosophy but answers abound in the Wisdom literature. Finding the answer would mean following the advice of the Delphic Oracle.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Objects exist only within subjects' minds**.

That is, there is no *user26567* (it's your username on this group) for nature. For an electron or for a banana, there is no *user26567*. You can only exist in other people's minds.

In the present interaction, you and me discussing, the **object** *user26567* exists in the mind of the **subject** *RodolfoAP*. If you answer my comment, I (the subject, from my perspective) will read it tomorrow and I will remember you (an object, from my perspective).

This means that a subject remembers (memory and knowledge) other persons (objects), and therefore it can interact with them. In the memory of most human subjects, there are objects (electrons, cars, bananas, shirts and other people) and a very important exception: he, himself as an object. That means that me, as a subject, remember you as an object and also remember me myself as an object. That is what makes me *me*. It is just my subjective memory. Although I change all the time, for my mind I keep being the same. This idea is easy to grasp with a river: although the river changes all the time, it is the same for me; has the same name, same location, same color, etc.

The initial statement (**objects exist only within subjects' minds**) is what an old group of philosophers called the *empiricists* suggested, **John Locke, David Hume, George Berkeley**. If you feel keen on the subject, you can read some introductions to their ideas, later refined by Immanuel Kant, although this last is really complex to read directly, without someone to guide you.